# Not Able To Include A Simple View In a Custom Notification?

Tags: android, android-layout, view, notifications

In my `app` i am building a custom `notification` with a `big view` of about `150dp`.

The `layout` is given below

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagenotileft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imagenotileft" />

     <View
      android:id="@+id/view"
      android:layout_width="365dp"
      android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_2"
      android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_23"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_below="@+id/title"
      android:background="@color/comunica_app_light_grey" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imagenotileft" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagenotiright"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:padding="10dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The `View` component is causing the `app` to crash when create `notification` function is called.There is nothing wrong with `code` part because it perfectly inflates without the `View` component.

The log during error is given below.

```
         Unrecognized GLES max version string in extensions: ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 
12-21 10:27:36.504 1701-1701/? E/StatusBar: couldn't inflate view for notification edu.uoc.app.comunica.dev/0x0
                                            android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.view.View
                                            Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.view.View
                                            Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Class not allowed to be inflated android.view.View
                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.failNotAllowed(LayoutInflater.java:683)
                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:634)
                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:700)
                                                at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:68)
                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:717)
                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:785)
                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                                                at android.widget.RemoteViews.inflateView(RemoteViews.java:3198)
                                                at android.widget.RemoteViews.apply(RemoteViews.java:3162)
                                                at com.android.systemui.statusbar.BaseStatusBar.inflateViews(BaseStatusBar.java:1667)
                                                at com.android.systemui.statusbar.BaseStatusBar.createNotificationViews(BaseStatusBar.java:2171)
                                                at com.android.systemui.statusbar.phone.PhoneStatusBar.addNotification(PhoneStatusBar.java:1407)
                                                at com.android.systemui.statusbar.BaseStatusBar$7$2.run(BaseStatusBar.java:634)
                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
12-21 10:27:36.528 29283-29283/edu.uoc.app.comunica.dev E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: edu.uoc.app.comunica.dev, PID: 29283
                                                                          android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package edu.uoc.app.comunica.dev: Couldn't expand RemoteViews for: StatusBarNotification(pkg=edu.uoc.app.comunica.dev user=UserHandle{0} id=0 tag=null key=0|edu.uoc.app.comunica.dev|0|null|10115: Notification(pri=0 contentView=edu.uoc.app.comunica.dev/0x7f0c002a vibrate=null sound=null tick defaults=0x0 flags=0x10 color=0x00000000 vis=PRIVATE))
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

I can't figure out whats causing this from the log.

Please, provide a solution.

Comment: where is this  layout `android:layout_below="@+id/send_date"` ?
,`TextView` and `View` have same id why?

Comment: sorry ,the question has been edited

Answer (score 0):

You have added this id for both the view

```
 android:id="@+id/title"
```

and the following id is not assigned to any of the view

```
@+id/send_date
```

this may be the issue

Comment: you have misses the first line of the layout file. ie <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>. try adding this and check.

Answer (score 0):

You must add all constructors needed for custom view. If you use android studio find Code->Generate, then "constructor", then check all available constructors, in next window you must uncheck all class properties, and then IDE generate this constructors for you.

```
public class CustomView extends View {    
    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(attrs);
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(attrs);
    }
}
```

Comment: he's talking about notification. I've the same problem as he for now